# py2neo Cypher Transaction "Create Index on..."

Tags: py2neo

I'am trying to create indexes in an empty neo4j 2.1.2 Database using py2neo (1.6.4)

I tried the following code:

```
from py2neo import cypher

session = cypher.Session("http://localhost:7474")
tx = session.create_transaction()
tx.append("CREATE INDEX ON :Net(name)")
tx.append("CREATE INDEX ON :Key(name)")
tx.append("CREATE INDEX ON :Prop(name)")
tx.commit
```

The code is running without errors, but nothing is done with the database.

If I do the check in the neo4j browser entering

```
:schema
```

I get the answer

```
No indexes

No constraints
```

If I enter the cypher query by hand

```
CREATE INDEX ON :Net(name)
```

followed by

```
:schema
```

I get the correct answer

```
Indexes

  ON :Net(name) ONLINE  

No constraints
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `tx.commit()`, not `tx.commit`. Your code is running without error because `tx.commit` is printing the `tx.commit` method, which is fine to do but if you want to send the transactions use `tx.commit()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't see it. :-(

Comment: Well spotted Nicole, you got there before me :-)